# Installing mysql server with postgresql

Tags: mysql, postgresql, database

I'm using backbox 4.4 which it was built-in with postgresql. Yesterday i think about "can i installing mysql database along side postgresql database ? ", i want to learn database connection but i so unfamiliar with postgresql, what i want to ask is :

1. Can postgresql and mysql run together in the same machine ?
2. If it can't, why so?
3. If it can, can you tell me how to configure mysql database to run with postgresql ? Or give me some reference.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can postgresql and mysql run together in the same machine ?

yes.

> If it can, can you tell me how to configure mysql database to run with postgresql ? Or give me some reference.

Ehm. There is no conflict between the 2 so you install [mysql](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/mysql.html) the normal way (`sudo apt-get install mysql-server`) , you install [postgres](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL) (`sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib`) the normal way. And then you basically create a user, set permissions and create a database. Using some kind of software to create a DBI connector and of you go.

The 2 run on different ports so there is nothing to hinder each other. The only thing: both will try to use the most out of your machine and compete for I/O, network access and memory so one of them is likely to slow down significantly if the other is doing something heavy.